# Keyboard shouldPersist using @gorhom/bottomsheet

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, textinput, bottom-sheet, flatlist

This is the outline of my code:

```
<BottomSheet
  ref={bottomSheetRef}
  index={0}
  snapPoints={snapPoints}
  onChange={(index) => {
    handleSheetChanges(index);
    if (index === 1) {
      setFetching(true);
    } else if (index === 0) {
      setFetching(false);
    }
    textinputRef.current.blur();
  }}
  keyboardBlurBehavior="restore"
  keyboardBehavior="interactive"
>
 <BottomSheetFlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    keyboardDismissMode="none"
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Comment
        key={item.id}
        handleLikeComment={handleLikeComment}
        comment={item}
        setIsKeyboard={setIsKeyboard}
        handleReplyOnComment={handleReplyOnComment}
        setFetching={setFetching}
      />
    )}
    refreshing={loading}
    onRefresh={() => setFetching(true)}
  />
  // Rest of code
</BottomSheet>
```

In Textinput I am using `BottomSheetTextInput`.
The problem is when the keyboard is open and I try to press on a button, the keyboard gets dismissed instead.
I tried also using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` instead of `keyboardDismissMode="none"` but it didn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by setting the `keyboardDismissMode` prop to `'on-drag'`, which will only dismiss the keyboard when the user starts dragging the BottomSheet content. This way, the keyboard will remain open when the user taps on a button or other non-text input elements.